# Optimizing list of query selectors adding a class

Tags: javascript

Hi guys I wrote the following code:

```
 function flyoutFirstHeadline() {
    document.querySelectorAll('.category-top-navigation__item--column-1 .category-top-navigation__item__headline')[0].classList.add('category-top-navigation__item__headline--first');
    document.querySelectorAll('.category-top-navigation__item--column-2 .category-top-navigation__item__headline')[0].classList.add('category-top-navigation__item__headline--first');
    document.querySelectorAll('.category-top-navigation__item--column-3 .category-top-navigation__item__headline')[0].classList.add('category-top-navigation__item__headline--first');
 }
```

Basically I am just adding some class to the first occurrence of `.category-top-navigation__item__headline` for each column that I have in the layout. I have a max of 3 columns starting from 1.

I am thinking about ways to optimize and make my code prettier.

I am thinking that maybe its better performing to do a loop which runs over the category column numbers and increments by 1 every time it runs until it reaches 3. Or perhaps there is some better way to do it?

Comment: Pure performance wise, I think your approach is the fastest. You could use 'querySelector' instead of 'querySelectorAll'. I personal also think it is readable code

Comment: Adding to what @Stefan said, I'd reckon querySelector() is actually faster because it matches *only* the first such element, rather than matching everything and handing you the first as querySelectorAll()[0] does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not get the headline elements and assign the class? There doesn't seem to be any need to include the column class too.

```js
function flyoutFirstHeadline() {
  const
    headLines = document.querySelectorAll('.category-top-navigation__item__headline:first-child');
    
  for(let index=0; index < headLines.length; index++) {
    headLines[index].classList.add('category-top-navigation__item__headline--first');
  }
}


flyoutFirstHeadline();
```

```css
.category-top-navigation__item__headline--first {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=".category-top-navigation__item--column-1">
  <h1 class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">Col 1 / headline 1</h1>
  <h2 class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">Col 1 / headline 2</h2>
</div>

<div class=".category-top-navigation__item--column-2">
  <h1 class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">Col 2 / headline 1</h1>
  <h2 class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">Col 2 / headline 2</h2>
</div>

<div class=".category-top-navigation__item--column-3">
  <h1 class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">Col 3 / headline 1</h1>
  <h2 class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">Col 3 / headline 2</h2>
</div>
```

I've updated my answer. It applies a class to the first header element per column and makes its text blue.

Comment: Some columns have more then one headline, but I only need the extra class on the first headline.

Comment: Would you know how to add that functionality into your code?

Comment: I've updated my answer, I think it now does what you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can select a class name that starts with some particular substring with the selector string `[class^=someStartingSubStr"]`. So, you can select and change all elements you want at once with:

```
function flyoutFirstHeadline() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll(
      '[class^="category-top-navigation__item--column-"] .category-top-navigation__item__headline'
    ), (headline) => {
      headline.classList.add('category-top-navigation__item__headline--first');
    }
  );
}
```

Demo:

```js
function flyoutFirstHeadline() {
  Array.prototype.forEach.call(
    document.querySelectorAll('[class^="column-"] .headline'),
    (headline) => {
      headline.classList.add('highlight');
    }
  );
}
flyoutFirstHeadline();
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="column-1">
  <div class="headline">headline</div>
</div>
<div class="column-2">
  <div class="headline">headline</div>
</div>
<div class="column-3">
  <div class="headline">headline</div>
</div>
```

Also note that if you only want to select *the first* element that matches a selector (like you were doing with your original code), you should use `querySelector`, and not `querySelectorAll` plus `[0]`.

Comment: be careful with nodeList.forEach. Internet explorer is not supporting this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach

Answer (score 0):

A solution focusing on clarity and flexibility:

1. no magic values
2. use `for..of` for iterables
3. commonly used functions aliased with short name
4. flexible element matches with attribute selector
5. long strings divided into easy to manage chunks

```js
function flyoutFirstHeadline() {
  const firstHeadlineSelector = [
    '[class^="category-top-navigation__item--column-"]',
    '.category-top-navigation__item__headline:first-child'
  ].join(' ');

  const newClass = 'category-top-navigation__item__headline--first';

  for (const el of $$(firstHeadlineSelector)) {
    el.classList.add(newClass);
  }
}


// helpers

const $$ = document.querySelectorAll.bind(document);

flyoutFirstHeadline()
```

```css
[class^="category-top-navigation__item--column-"] {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

.category-top-navigation__item__headline--first {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="category-top-navigation__item--column-1">category 1
  <div class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">headline 1</div>
  <div class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">headline 2</div>
</div>
<div class="category-top-navigation__item--column-2">category 2
  <div class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">headline 1</div>
  <div class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">headline 2</div>
</div>
<div class="category-top-navigation__item--column-3">category 3
  <div class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">headline 1</div>
  <div class="category-top-navigation__item__headline">headline 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

## Assign a `className` to Each Tag at the Top of Each Column

### Changes

#### HTML Layout

I guessed on how your layout is:

- each column is `<section class='col`<sup>✱</sup>`'>`
- each column has two `<h2 class='headline'>`, one on top and one on the bottom.

---

#### [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) in [`.classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList)

I also shortened the `classNames` in `.classList` to keep me sane:

> `.category-top-navigation__item--column-`<sup>✱</sup> === `.col`<sup>✱</sup> === `<section class="col`<sup>✱</sup>`">`
>      `.category-top-navigation__item__headline` === `.headline` === `<h2 class="headline">`
>      `.category-top-navigation__item__headline--first` === `.first` === `<h2 class="headline first">`
>   <sup>✱=1,2,3</sup> ex. `.col2`

---

### Solutions

#### CSS Pseudo-class [`:first-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:first-of-type)

When applied to the `section h2.headline:first-of-type` selector, it works like this:

> Find all `<h2 class="headline">` that are the `:first-of-` its `type` (i.e.`type: <h2>`) within its parent element: `<section>`.

---

#### JavaScript Collecting Tags Into a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList)

To utilize the previously mentioned selector, [`document.querySelectorAll("`**section h2.headline:first-of-type**`")`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) is perfect. The result is an [`array-like Object`](http://2ality.com/2013/05/quirk-array-like-objects.html)  (or NodeList) specifically consisting of the three `<h2 class="headline">` positioned as the first `<h2>` within its own column `<section>`.

When dealing with multiple Elements, Numbers, Strings, Objects, etc. you need to iterate (or loop) through each member of that group (i.e. NodeList, [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection), Array, Plain Object, array-like Object, etc.):

`first` is an array-like Object/NodeList:

> ```
> var first = document.querySelectorAll("section h2.headline:first-of-type");
> ```

#### Iterate (Loop) Through NodeList with a **[`for()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)** Loop

In order to access each `<h2>` within `first`, you must iterate through `first`:

> ```
> for (let i=0; i < first.length; i++) {...
> ```

- for each loop thru `first`: **[`for(...`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration)**
- start the loop count at zero: `let i = 0;`
- stop when total number of loops is reached: `i < first.length; // 3`
- increment the loop count by 1: `i++) {...`

Within each iteration of the `for()` loop, `className`: `.first`<sup>†</sup> is added to a `<h2 class="headline">`:

> ```
> first[i].classList.add('first')
> ```
>
> <sup>†</sup> `.first { text-decoration: underline }`

---

### Demo

If successful, three `<h2>` that are positioned at the top of their columns `<section>` will be underlined.

```js
function firstHeadline() {
  var first = document.querySelectorAll('section h2.headline:first-of-type');
  for (let i = 0; i < first.length; i++) {
    first[i].classList.add('first');
  }
}

// Optional
function dateTime(time) {
  var node = document.querySelector(time);
  var option = {
    weekday: 'long',
    year: 'numeric',
    month: 'long',
    day: 'numeric'
  };
  var D = new Date().toLocaleDateString("en-US", option);
  node.setAttribute('date-time', D);
  node.textContent = D;
}

dateTime('time');

firstHeadline();
```

```css
html,
body {
  font: 500 16px/1.2 Times;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

h1 {
  line-height: 2;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 5%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -75%);
}

h1,
h2,
sub {
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
}

article {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 98%;
  height: auto;
}

section {
  width: 32%;
  min-height: 100%;
  border: 0.5px inset rgba(51, 51, 51, 0.15);
  padding: 3px;
}

p {
  margin: 3px;
  text-align: justify;
  font-size: .75rem;
}

header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

header,
footer {
  height: 10%;
  width: 96%;
}

.headline,
h1 {
  letter-spacing: 1.5px
}

time {
  font-size: 0.85rem;
}

.first {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <h1>Main Title</h1>
  <time datetime=""></time>
</header>
<hr>
<article>
  <section class='col1'>
    <h2 class='headline'>Headline 1A</h2>
    <p>Cras pellentesque tempor ex, vitae pulvinar risus lobortis nec. Sed quis aliquet nulla. Quisque egestas lectus et facilisis sodales.</p>
    <sub></sub>
    <h2 class='headline'>Headline 1B</h2>
    <p>Maecenas elementum efficitur nibh pretium pellentesque. Cras vitae ipsum nisi. Nam sapien justo, faucibus et metus sed, vestibulum bibendum eros. Nunc luctus gravida ex, vel feugiat magna porta ut. Nam et pretium risus.</p>
    <sub></sub>
  </section>
  <section class='col2'>
    <h2 class='headline'>Headline 2A</h2>
    <p>Sed et facilisis nulla, non pulvinar nisl. Duis ultricies nisi luctus sem aliquam ornare. Curabitur rutrum lorem vitae turpis eleifend, sed dignissim nisi ultricies. Sed efficitur interdum est.</p>
    <sub></sub>
    <h2 class='headline'>Headline 2B</h2>
    <p>Pellentesque mollis viverra orci et blandit. Proin a sem fermentum magna vehicula tinidunt. Proin tempor orci ut ullamcorper tristique.</p>
    <sub></sub>
  </section>
  <section class='col3'>
    <h2 class='headline'>Headline 3A</h2>
    <p>Suspendisse ultricies, sapien nec elementum lacinia, quam enim maximus lorem, eu hendrerit nisi libero non velit. Nam eget mattis turpis, non lacinia ante. Fusce viverra sem sit amet sodales vulputate.</p>
    <sub></sub>
    <h2 class='headline'>Headline 3B</h2>
    <p>Duis nisi nibh, ultrices sit amet enim ac, scelerisque dictum justo. Morbi tempor ante sit amet ante maximus consectetur.</p>
    <sub></sub>
  </section>
</article>
<hr>
<footer>
  <address></address>
</footer>
```

Answer (score 0):

When speaking performance, what you have is already good. Though like @BoltClock said in the comments, `.querySelector(...)` instead of `.querySelectorAll(...)[0]` would be even better, it simply picks the first element.

If you're looking for "prettier" ..

```
document
.querySelectorAll('.category-top-navigation__item__headline:first-child')
.forEach(el => el.classList.add('category-top-navigation__item__headline--first'))
```

And, even prettier, with arguably even better readability ..

```
const headline = 'category-top-navigation__item__headline'

document.querySelectorAll(`${headline}:first-child`)
.forEach(el => el.classList.add(`${headline}--first`))
```

Please note, the answer above makes use of the `first-child` trick from [Thijs's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52254255/2206733).